# UV Texture Bleeds Over

Tags: texturing, uv

I've nearly finishing texturing a Pelican in Blender painting on UV maps from photoshop and importing the result on the Pelican, everything is fine except for the beak, where parts of the uv are bleeding over into each other particularly in little corners. (See Image) other than cutting up the mesh of the Pelican again is there any other way to fix this? I have the mirror modifier applied as well.

[image]

Comment: Please add an image of the wireframes for this type of a question.

Comment: I can't seem to add another image

Comment: Maybe as a link? If you don't have a https://imgur.com account, it's okay, you can add a picture there even without an account.

Answer (score -1):

Try switching your subdivision surface modifier from Catmull-Clark to Simple.

Comment: Tried that, surface goes all blocky and can't seem to set it back to normal, Thanks for the tip though.